# Web crawler - following links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Please bear with me. I am quite new at Python - but having a lot of fun. I am trying to code a web crawler that crawls through election results from the last referendum in Denmark. I have managed to extract all the relevant links from the main page. And now I want Python to follow each of the 92 links and gather 9 pieces of information from each of those pages. But I am so stuck. Hope you can give me a hint.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
import urllib2 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# This is the original url http://www.kmdvalg.dk/

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.kmdvalg.dk/').read())

my_list = []
all_links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in all_links:
    link2 = link["href"]
    my_list.append(link2)

for i in my_list[1:93]:
    print i

# The output shows all the links that I would like to follow and gather information from. How do I do that?
```

Comment: Can you mention more about 9 pieces information you want to grab inside each links?

Comment: Wow - you guys are awsome!! I will have to spent some time trying to understand your solutions. I will be back as soon as I have understod them. THANKS A LOT!

Comment: @titipat: Yes. Take a look on this sub-site. I want to grab "stemmeberettigede / number of people who can vote", "Optalte stemmer / counted votes", "JA-stemmer / People who votes yes", "NEJ-stemmer / people who voted no", "Blanke stemmer / blank votes",  "Ugyldige stemmer / Invalid votes" and the name of the municipality (Assenskredsen in this case)

Comment: Ahh, I see @Metods, I will update my solution soon. For `lxml`, it basically goes through each html tag which you can find by inspect element on simple web browser. `/text()` will grab text inside the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple approach would be to iterate through your list of urls and parse them each individually:

```
for url in my_list:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
    # then parse each page individually here
```

Alternatively, you could speed things up significantly using [Futures](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests-futures).

```
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

def my_parse_function(html):
    """Use this function to parse each page"""
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    all_paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
    return all_paragraphs

session = FuturesSession(max_workers=5)
futures = [session.get(url) for url in my_list]

page_results = [my_parse_function(future.result()) for future in results]
```

Comment: This is just so great. My script now works thanks to your comment about iterating through my list of urls.

Comment: UPS - wasn't done. I am sure all other suggestions on this page are cooler - but I choose the peace of advice I could understand. Thanks. This is my final code that works - if you have suggestions to make it smarter please let me know. Best regards from Methods.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my solution using `lxml`. It's similar to `BeautifulSoup`

```
import lxml
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.kmdvalg.dk/main')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
my_list = tree.xpath('//div[@class="LetterGroup"]//a/@href') # grab all link
print 'Length of all links = ', len(my_list)
```

`my_list` is a list consist of all links. And now you can use for loop to scrape information inside each page.

We can for loop through each links. Inside each page, you can extract information as example. This is only for the top table.

```
table_information = []
for t in my_list:
    page_detail = requests.get(t)
    tree = html.fromstring(page_detail.content)
    table_key = tree.xpath('//td[@class="statusHeader"]/text()')
    table_value = tree.xpath('//td[@class="statusText"]/text()') + tree.xpath('//td[@class="statusText"]/a/text()')
    table_information.append(zip([t]*len(table_key), table_key, table_value))
```

For table below the page,

```
table_information_below = []
for t in my_list:
    page_detail = requests.get(t)
    tree = html.fromstring(page_detail.content)
    l1 = tree.xpath('//tr[@class="tableRowPrimary"]/td[@class="StemmerNu"]/text()')
    l2 = tree.xpath('//tr[@class="tableRowSecondary"]/td[@class="StemmerNu"]/text()')
    table_information_below.append([t]+l1+l2)
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

This would be my solution for your problem

```
 import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def spider():
    url = "http://www.kmdvalg.dk/main"
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')

    for link in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'LetterGroup'}):
        anc = link.find('a')
        href = anc.get('href')

        print(anc.getText())
        print(href)
        # spider2(href) call a second function from here that is similar to this one(making url = to herf)
        spider2(href)
        print("\n")


def spider2(linktofollow):
    url = linktofollow
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')

    for link in soup.findAll('tr', {'class': 'tableRowPrimary'}):
        anc = link.find('td')

        print(anc.getText())
    print("\n")


spider()
```

its not done... i only get a simple element from the table but you get the idea and how its supposed to work.

Comment: instead of find('td') in the second fucntion you could use findAll using the name of td class you want to find.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final code that works smooth. Please let me know if I could have done it smarter!

```
import urllib2 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import codecs

f = codecs.open("eu2015valg.txt", "w", encoding="iso-8859-1")

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.kmdvalg.dk/').read())

liste = []

alle_links = soup.find_all("a")

for link in alle_links:
    link2 = link["href"]
    liste.append(link2)

for url in liste[1:93]:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode('iso-8859-1'))
    tds = soup.findAll('td')
    stemmernu = soup.findAll('td', class_='StemmerNu')
    print >> f, tds[5].string,";",tds[12].string,";",tds[14].string,";",tds[16].string,";", stemmernu[0].string,";",stemmernu[1].string,";",stemmernu[2].string,";",stemmernu[3].string,";",stemmernu[6].string,";",stemmernu[8].string,";",'\r\n'

f.close()
```